# ¿Como se logra que el archivo de salida tenga la fecha y hora incluida en su nombre?

Tags: cron

Tengo el siguiente comando que es ejecutado por un cron cada 2 minutos y si funciona bien:

```
*/2 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/jamoncitoi1.sql
```

como se puede notar genera un archivo llamado jamoncitoi1.sql pero siempre se esta reescribiendo por que el nombre no cambia, quisiera modificar el comando ahí mismo sin mandar llamar un script para que se guarde con la fecha y hora de ese momento, de esa forma no se va a sobreescribir.
Alguna ídea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con la respuesta que te he dado en [Crear fichero con fecha y hora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/395286/crear-fichero-con-fecha-y-hora/395292#395292) podrías guiarte de como crearlos y mirar otros formatos.

**Aún así**, en el `cron` debes escapar los caracteres especiales.

Si quiero crear un fichero de la siguiente forma:

```
2020-10-07-20:23:01.txt
```

Es decir:

```
# Año-Mes-Día-Hora-Minuto-Segundo
# YYYY-mm-dd-HH:MM:SS
```

Podrías crearlo de la siguiente forma:

```
touch $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S).txt
```

Pero para escapar los caracteres en el `cron` deberás colocarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
* * * * * touch /home/usuario/rutaDondeCreoElFichero/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S).txt
```

Por lo que lo que **necesitas quedaría más o menos así**:

```
*/2 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -h216.70.69.75 -uivanchido -pFlystar3979@@@ bdivan > /Users/ivancaballerocano/Documents/bdRespaldo/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H:\%M:\%S)_jamoncitoi1.sql
```

Comment: SIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   !!!!!! Así si jala!!!!!!   Por finnnnnnnn!!!!   Muchas Gracias!!!    Por eso no jalaba por que el cron necesita escapar los caracteres y eso no tenía idea.

Comment: No te preocupes. Para eso estamos. Saludos.