# Crear fichero con fecha y hora específica con "touch"

Tags: bash, touch

¿Cómo se le hace para que el comando touch de Unix me arroje un nombre de archivo cuyo nombre tenga la fecha y hora?

```
touch miarchivo
```

Algo así pero que arroje el archivo `miarchivo2020-10-7` y la hora también.

Comment: Hola, Iván. Trata de añadir ejemplo con lo que hayas intentado para que no te puntúen de forma negativa, además del `touch` que sirve para crear ficheros y cambiar timestamps, algo relacionado con la fecha, como con el comando `date`. Te he dejado un ejemplo en la respuesta.

Comment: Para eso existe la documentación: `man touch`

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es un problema de programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crearlo de la siguiente forma:

```
touch ejemplo_$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' )
```

Donde puedes reemplazar `ejemplo_` por cualquier nombre que quieras que preceda a la fecha.

En mí mí caso al momento de la creación el nombre es el siguiente:

```
ejemplo_2020-10-07_20-02-15
```

Dónde:

- **%Y** : Es el año.
- **%m** : Es el mes.
- **%d** : Es el día.
- **%H** : Es la hora.
- **%M** : Es el minuto.
- **%S** : Es el segundo.

```
Puedes uno o varios en el orden que quieras, por ejemplo:
# date '+%Y-%m-%d'
2020-10-07
```

Tienes muchos más [formatos](https://www.elmundoenbits.com/2013/04/date-format-bash-linux.html#.X34ENM8zZhE) que quizá te sirvan.

Nota, `$()` ejecuta lo que hay dentro, captura la salida y se lo puedes pasar a otro comando, por ejemplo:

```
# Si hago un ls, me devuelve contenido:
-> ls
1  2  3
# Puedo imprimir ese contenido a través de un echo:
-> echo $(ls)
1 2 3
```

Comment: Ah super bien muchas gracias!

Comment: Nada. Para eso estamos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Solo una pequeña nota al margen: recuerda poner entre comillas las expansiones de comandos `$(...)` para evitar los efectos de [*filename expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) y [*word splitting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html). Incluso si el resultado de la expansión no contiene caracteres especiales o espacios en blanco, el *word splitting* aun puede afectar si la variable `IFS` tiene asignado un valor distinto al que viene por defecto.

Comment: Gracias @FastedCoyote por la recomendación. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos